# How can I draw this Bottomn Nav bar with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bottomnavigationview

I just have this for the moment.

[image: TabBarReactNative]

I need to resize the width and draw this little hole under my big plus button like this model.

[image: Sketch TabBar]

I searched on internet for a long time and I didn't find nothing

Comment: make a div with position: absolute and give it height, width, background color & border radius bottom left right

Comment: You have to use an svg on the bar under the round button.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it different:

In that white bar, add overflow: hidden. Then add a circle with css thats grey, and position it -50% top so only half of the circle shows. then add the icon ontop of that.

Comment: but I need the circle to be transparent :/

Comment: It doesnt need to be transparent, the grey will mask it